# Pytest is searching conftest one level higher

Tags: python, pytest

I'm trying to run `pytest` on a machine but `pytest` keeps sourcing `conftest` one level higher. The directory I'm working with does not have an `__init__.py`

```
17:09:36  /shared/functionaltests/kubernetesTests
17:09:36  + rm __init__.py
17:09:36  + ls
17:09:36  conftest.py
17:09:36  helper_functions.py
17:09:36  kubernetesTests.groovy
17:09:36  readme.txt
17:09:36  test_complete.py
17:09:36  + pytest ./
17:09:36  ImportError while loading conftest '/shared/functionaltests/conftest.py'.
17:09:36  ../conftest.py:8: in <module>
17:09:36      import functionaltests.panda_functions as pf
17:09:36  ../panda_functions.py:1: in <module>
17:09:36      import pandas
17:09:36  E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

-Removed __init__.py
-launching pytest using py.test and python -m pytest
-using --rootdir=./
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an expected behaviour since you don't explicitly specify what the root dir is (by e.g. putting a `pytest.ini` in the dir) and put `conftest.py`s in parent dirs. `pytest` will go up the parent dirs, looking for `pytest.ini`, will encounter `conftest.py` and count the dir as rootdir itself or rootdir's child. If you want to make `kubernetesTests` a rootdir, put an empty `pytest.ini` in it:

```
touch /shared/functionaltests/kubernetesTests/pytest.ini`
```

Now the parent `conftest`s won't be loaded.

Another solution is to fix the imports by adding `/shared` to `sys.path`:

```
PYTHONPATH=/shared pytest
```

Now `/shared` continues to be the rootdir (as it should be) and the parent `conftest.py`s  are loaded and executed.